# How do I disable the huge rounded corners on the bar splitting apps on Android 12?

Tags: lineageos, android-12, multitasking, multi-window

If I split the screen to see two apps, the splitting bar has huge rounded corners covering the apps. Below is a screenshot showing that. There, the bar covers parts of the video and parts of the search box. How do I disable the rounded corners?

I have Poco F2 Pro with LineageOS 19.

[image: demonstration of the bar with rounded corners covering parts of the apps]